# Correct way to call a Bash function from all sessions

Tags: shell-script, bashrc, function, source, javascript

I use Ubuntu with Bash and I have a file hosting a script with 5 functions.

Sometimes I want to call some function of these functions (but not all of them), directly from the CLI.

I could say it's quite like executing a file with an `alias`, but in this case, I target a particular function **within** a file and not a file by itself.

---

What is the correct way to do so?

I thought of sourcing the file from my users `"$HOME"/.bashrc` but that would execute the entire file with all functions and I totally don't want that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My approach of sourcing the file from `"$HOME"/.bashrc` is good, but I missed this:

I first started to program in vanilla JavaScript, and there, there is no such things as shell session, `bashrc` files, and sourcing in the current session (in a way that effect only this session or this and 1 or more others).

In Bash, what I should do is create the file with the functions but without calls, then source it (execute it in the current session). I shouldn't call them in the file because then all out them would be called when the file is sourced.

Given it is sourced from my users `bashrc` file, each time I move to another session, the file would be re-sourced for me, in that session as well, and I could call the functions regular there as well.

---

Thinking in a vanilla JavaScript paradigm on this Bash issue is what inhibited me from reaching the answer directly.